# Have Madhwa's methods of scripture-interpretation been criticized by later commentators?

Tags: madhwa, critique, interpretation

Madhwa's methods have been characterized as

> "often Sri Madhva's arguments rely on nuances and ingenious usage of grammar, often lending unusual meanings to very familiar and straightforward words."

the most noteworthy case being:

wiki:

> Tat Tvam Asi (Devanagari: तत्त्वमसि, Vedic: tát túvam ási), a Sanskrit phrase, translated variously as "Thou art that," (That thou art, That art thou, You are that, or That you are, or You're it) is one of the Mahāvākyas (Grand Pronouncements) in Vedantic Sanatana Dharma. It originally occurs in the Chandogya Upanishad 6.8.7,[1] in the dialogue between Uddalaka and his son Śvetaketu; it appears at the end of a section, and is repeated at the end of the subsequent sections as a refrain. The meaning of this saying is that the Self - in its original, pure, primordial state - is wholly or partially identifiable or identical with the Ultimate Reality that is the ground and origin of all phenomena.

According to Madhwa:

> “Sa atmaa-tat tvam asi” in Sanskrit is actually “Sa atma-atat tvam asi” or “Atma (soul), thou art, thou art not God”.

What are some examples of criticism of Madhwa's scripture-interpretations, not necessarily on sectarian grounds?

note: this question has been edited and does not focus solely on Mahavakyas, and is clearly not a duplicate of this

[What are the exact interpretations of four Mahavakyas by Dvaita, Vishishtadvaita and Advaita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30105/what-are-the-exact-interpretations-of-four-mahavakyas-by-dvaita-vishishtadvait)

question.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30105/what-are-the-exact-interpretations-of-four-mahavakyas-by-dvaita-vishishtadvaita

Comment: @rickross it is not a duplicate - it is not asking  for the interpretations of various sects - it is asking for their comments on Madhwa's interpretation.

Comment: @SK  I don't have textual reference, but I have heard from upanyasams by sri vaishnava scholars that interpreting that verse as "atat tvam asi" goes against the context the verse is in, and they say that Madhvacharya's interpretations of scripture are generally unorthodox and awkward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the exact interpretations of four Mahavakyas by Dvaita, Vishishtadvaita and Advaita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30105/what-are-the-exact-interpretations-of-four-mahavakyas-by-dvaita-vishishtadvaita)

Comment: third person to ask this, already answered.

Comment: Okay only slightly different. BTW I have not close voted.@SK